# Cannot install DifferentialEquations package to Julia

Tags: julia

When I try to install DifferentialEquations package, I face the following problem:

```
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package DimensionalPlotRecipes [c619ae07]:  
DimensionalPlotRecipes [c619ae07] log:  
 ├─possible versions are: [0.1.0-0.1.1, 0.2.0, 1.0.0] or uninstalled  
 ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with RecipesBase [3cdcf5f2] to versions: uninstalled  
 │ └─RecipesBase [3cdcf5f2] log:  
 │   ├─possible versions are: [0.4.0, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.7.0, 0.8.0] or uninstalled  
 │   └─restricted to versions 0.8.0 by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions 0.8.0  
 └─restricted by compatibility requirements with DifferentialEquations [0c46a032] to versions: [0.1.0-0.1.1, 0.2.0, 1.0.0] — no versions left  
  └─DifferentialEquations [0c46a032] log:  
     ├─possible versions are: [5.0.0, 5.1.0, 5.2.0-5.2.1, 5.3.0-5.3.1, 6.0.0, 6.1.0, 6.2.0, 6.3.0, 6.4.0, 6.6.0, 6.7.0, 6.8.0, 6.9.0, 6.10.0-6.10.1] or uninstalled  
     └─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions [5.0.0, 5.1.0, 5.2.0-5.2.1, 5.3.0-5.3.1, 6.0.0, 6.1.0, 6.2.0, 6.3.0, 6.4.0, 6.6.0, 6.7.0, 6.8.0, 6.9.0, 6.10.0-6.10.1]
```

There are installed packages:

```
[a93c6f00] DataFrames v0.20.0  
[7073ff75] IJulia v1.21.1  
[91a5bcdd] Plots v0.29.0  
[d330b81b] PyPlot v2.8.2  
[3cdcf5f2] RecipesBase v0.8.0
```

Julia version is 1.3.1 and operating system is Windows 10.
Any suggestions?

Comment: If you have RecipesBase installed already, try removing it  and then adding DifferentialEquations

Answer (score 2):

The first comment helped a lot!

First, I tried to remove `RecipesBase`, but it did not help, because it founded unsatisfiable requirements with this package in `Plots`.
Next, I remove `Plots` and then installed `DifferentialEquations` successfully.

Installation of `Plots` (in the end) downgraded some other packages. Everything works fine now, but when I run `using DifferentialEquations` in `Jupyter` there are a lot of warnings about the precompilation. This is the first one:

```
┌ Warning: Module RecipesBase with build ID 1818350963268401 is missing from the cache.
│ This may mean RecipesBase [3cdcf5f2-1ef4-517c-9805-6587b60abb01] does not support precompilation but is imported by a module that does.
└ @ Base loading.jl:1011
```

Anyway, both packages work.

Comment: I'm upgrading all of the DiffEq RecipesBase dependencies today. Sorry for the hiccup.